# How do I control TaskProtection when using Java Spring and AWS Autoscaling?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs

I am working on a Java Spring Web Service using @SqsLister to hand items on an SQS Queue. My cluster is configured to use start and stop tasks based on the depth of the SQS Queue. This part works fine.

I am worried about a task being terminated while the previously dequeued item is still being processed.

Does Spring support this in any way? Is there a preferred way of handing this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement that yourself in your tasks. Basically it is done through [ecs task termination protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-scale-in-protection.html), and AWS provides examples of how to do it:

- [Elastic Container Service (ECS) Task Protection Examples](https://github.com/aws-containers/ecs-task-protection-examples)

The examples are not for spring, but you have to implement something similar yourself in your application.